# What does "-ls" do when used with "find"?

Tags: command-line, find, manpage

According to `man find`:

> -ls
>
> True; list current file in **ls -dils** format on standard output. 
>   The block counts are of 1K blocks, unless the environment variable
>   POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, in which case 512-byte blocks are used.  See
>   the **UNUSUAL FILENAMES** section for  information about how unusual
>   characters in filenames are handled.

I don't understand the `ls -dils` part.

`man ls` has "-d list directories themselves, not their contents".

Consider a folder with three .png files:

```
$ ls
01-default.png  02-jungle.png  03-snow.png
$
```

I get

```
$ find . -type f -ls
 12983011     28 -rw-rw-r--   1 dkb    dkb       25964 Mar 10 17:28 ./01-default.png
 12982994     24 -rw-rw-r--   1 dkb    dkb       21857 Mar 10 17:28 ./03-snow.png
 12983031     28 -rw-rw-r--   1 dkb    dkb       25964 Mar 10 17:28 ./02-jungle.png
$
```

But, if the `-ls` means the same as `ls -dils`, I should see something similar with `ls -dils` but all I get is

```
$ ls -dils
13631944 4 drwxrwxr-x 2 dkb dkb 4096 Aug 30 21:22 .
$
```

Whereas, `ls -ils` is more like what I get with `find` used with `-ls`:

```
$ ls -ils
total 80
12983011 28 -rw-rw-r-- 1 dkb dkb 25964 Mar 10 17:28 01-default.png
12983031 28 -rw-rw-r-- 1 dkb dkb 25964 Mar 10 17:28 02-jungle.png
12982994 24 -rw-rw-r-- 1 dkb dkb 21857 Mar 10 17:28 03-snow.png
$
```

So I was wondering if there's a typo in the `man find` page and whether `ls -dils` should really be `ls ils` in the part I quoted at the top of the question.

Comment: It's equivalent to `ls -dils` *on the files found*, not on their containing directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For each file it finds**, the `find` command with the `-ls` action displays *that file* in a format similar to what this command would display, when you replace *`path`* with that file's path:

```
ls -dils path
```

This is to say that `find` with `-ls` is similar to running many commands that *start with* `ls -dils`, one for each file found. It is *not* similar to running this actual command with no path argument:

```
ls -dils
```

The `ls` command exhibits special behavior when run with no path arguments: it behaves as if a single path argument `.` has been passed. You've been comparing the behavior of the `find` command with `-ls` to the behavior of the `ls` command without path arguments, but you should compare its behavior to that of `ls` *with* path arguments. For example, try this:

```
ls -dils ./*
```

(Because `ls` sorts its output, as mentioned below, an even better comparison would be to many separate `ls -dils ./filename` commands, one for each *`filename`*.)

With those particular files, the output is the same with and without `-d`. However, `find` can find directories. You can see the difference between the `ls` commands with and without the `-d` option by creating a directory and trying both `ls -dils ./*` and `ls -dils ./*`. For example:

```
ek@Cord:~/tmp$ touch a b c
ek@Cord:~/tmp$ mkdir d
```

```
ek@Cord:~/tmp$ ls -dils ./*
147774362773104141 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek   0 Aug 30 12:35 ./a
 71213169107810485 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek   0 Aug 30 12:35 ./b
 23080948090377031 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek   0 Aug 30 12:35 ./c
 25051272927352243 0 drwxrwxrwx 1 ek ek 512 Aug 30 12:35 ./d
```

```
ek@Cord:~/tmp$ ls -ils ./*
147774362773104141 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek   0 Aug 30 12:35 ./a
 71213169107810485 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek   0 Aug 30 12:35 ./b
 23080948090377031 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek   0 Aug 30 12:35 ./c

./d:
total 0
```

To reiterate one particular important point: because **`find` with `-ls` is similar to running many separate `ls -dils path` commands**, it does not behave the same as any particular `ls` command. (It does behave *somewhat* similarly to an `ls -dils paths...`, where *`paths...`* is all the paths `find` found, but it's not all that similar to that either, because the `ls` command sorts its output, so the results would often appear in a different order.)

---

Another way to see this is to run a `find` command whose results include directories with the `-ls` action, and then run the corresponding `find` commands that use the `-exec` action to run actual `ls` commands with different options. For example:

```
ek@Cord:~/tmp$ find . -ls
54043195528455285      0 drwxrwxrwx   1 ek       ek            512 Aug 30 12:35 .
147774362773104141      0 -rw-rw-rw-   1 ek       ek              0 Aug 30 12:35 ./a
 71213169107810485      0 -rw-rw-rw-   1 ek       ek              0 Aug 30 12:35 ./b
 23080948090377031      0 -rw-rw-rw-   1 ek       ek              0 Aug 30 12:35 ./c
 25051272927352243      0 drwxrwxrwx   1 ek       ek            512 Aug 30 12:35 ./d
```

```
ek@Cord:~/tmp$ find . -exec ls -dils {} \;
54043195528455285 0 drwxrwxrwx 1 ek ek 512 Aug 30 12:35 .
147774362773104141 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek 0 Aug 30 12:35 ./a
71213169107810485 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek 0 Aug 30 12:35 ./b
23080948090377031 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek 0 Aug 30 12:35 ./c
25051272927352243 0 drwxrwxrwx 1 ek ek 512 Aug 30 12:35 ./d
```

```
ek@Cord:~/tmp$ find . -exec ls -ils {} \;
total 0
147774362773104141 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek   0 Aug 30 12:35 a
 71213169107810485 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek   0 Aug 30 12:35 b
 23080948090377031 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek   0 Aug 30 12:35 c
 25051272927352243 0 drwxrwxrwx 1 ek ek 512 Aug 30 12:35 d
147774362773104141 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek 0 Aug 30 12:35 ./a
71213169107810485 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek 0 Aug 30 12:35 ./b
23080948090377031 0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 ek ek 0 Aug 30 12:35 ./c
total 0
```

In the version that runs `-ls` without -`d`, the first entries displayed for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are the output of the *first* `ls` command run, with the path `.`. To verify this, try it with `-ok` in place of `-exec` (which operates interactively, prompting you before each command, and therefore makes clear which commands produce which outputs).

Comment: "You've been comparing the behavior of the find command with -ls to the behavior of the ls command without path arguments". Thanks! That cleared things up.